# How do you define specific label title for every activity in an Android app?

Tags: android

In the AndroidManifest.xml file, the statement:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

inserts the name of the app in every activity.I want to change this so that the Sign In page for instance displays "sign in", the Settings page displays "settings" and so on.
I have tried adding the line `android:labelFor="@string/sign_in_page_label"` to the `sign_in.xml` file but it won't work.What are my doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity use
setTitle("String");

Comment: Works like a charm.Thanks. But just out of curiosity, is this the only way?

Comment: I believe yes it is, since titlebar is created on runtime. kindly accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, add Android:label="@string/label name" to the activity you want to change the label.